# Circle drawn in a JPanel does not get drawn at the position of mouseClick

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent

I'm trying to create a program that lets the user move a circle in a JPanel, But I'm facing some problems.

My program:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class SixthProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GUI prog=new GUI("SixthProgram");
        prog.setBounds(350,250,500,250);
        prog.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class GUI extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener
{
    JButton color1, color2, color3 ,color4 ,color5;
    JPanel mainPan, colorPan;
    Color color=Color.BLACK;

    int x=0,y=0;

    public GUI(String header)
    {
        super(header);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        maker();

        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);

        add(mainPan , BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(colorPan, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void maker()
    {
        colorPan = new JPanel();

        Border raisedbevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        Border loweredbevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        Border compound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedbevel, loweredbevel);
        colorPan.setBorder(compound);

        colorPan.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        mainPan = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                //g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                //g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
                super.paintComponent(g); //Do the same thing as above(Clear JPanel)

                g.setColor(color);
                g.fillOval(x,y,50,50);
            }
        };

        color1 = new JButton();
        color2 = new JButton();
        color3 = new JButton();
        color4 = new JButton();
        color5 = new JButton();

        color1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        color2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        color3.setBackground(Color.RED);
        color4.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        color5.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        color1.addActionListener(this);
        color2.addActionListener(this);
        color3.addActionListener(this);
        color4.addActionListener(this);
        color5.addActionListener(this);

        colorPan.add(color1);
        colorPan.add(color2);
        colorPan.add(color3);
        colorPan.add(color4);
        colorPan.add(color5);

        colorPan.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) //MouseListener overrided methods
    {
        System.out.println("Exit");
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter");
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Release");
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Press");    

        if((e.getX()+50 <= getWidth())  &&
           (e.getY()+50 <= (getHeight() - colorPan.getHeight()))) // Preventing out of bounds
        {
            x=e.getX();
            y=e.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) //Press+Release=Click
    {
        System.out.println("Click");
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) //MouseMotionListener overrided methods
    {
        //System.out.println("Dragged to ("+ e.getX() +","+ e.getY() +")");

        if((e.getX()>=0 && e.getY()>=0) && 
           (e.getX()+50 <= getWidth())  &&
           (e.getY()+50 <= (getHeight() - colorPan.getHeight())) )
        {
            x=e.getX();
            y=e.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //System.out.println("Moved to ("+ e.getX() +","+ e.getY() +")");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        color = button.getBackground();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

The above code produces the expected output:

[image: OUTPUT]

The problems are:

1. When I drag the circle around, the circle doesn't seem to be drawn at the position of the mouse:

   [image: PROBLEM #1]

   In the above screenshot, I'm dragging the mouse , but the circle seems to be drawn at a position *below* the mouse.
2. The circle gets drawn behind the colorchooser JPanel(`colorPan`):

   [image: PROBLEM #2]

   I would like the circle, not to enter `colorPan`'s territory.
3. The circle get to move too far to the right:

   [image: PROBLEM #3]

   You can observe a part of the circle being outside the JPanel(`mainPan`).

I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with my `mouseDragged` method:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    //System.out.println("Dragged to ("+ e.getX() +","+ e.getY() +")");

    if((e.getX()>=0 && e.getY()>=0) && 
       (e.getX()+50 <= getWidth())  &&
       (e.getY()+50 <= (getHeight() - colorPan.getHeight())) )
    {
        x=e.getX();
        y=e.getY();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

but I can't seem to find the problem. Can anyone help me solve these problems?

Comment: I believe it is because when you draw the (0,0) coordinate of the window is the top left of the menu bar but when you click the (0,0) coordinate starts just beneath the menu bar so you are offset vertically by exactly 1 menu bar height.  In your mouseDragged function just change it to y = e.getY() - menuBarHeight;

Comment: King Popsicle is correct, though I think an easier approach would be to add your `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` to your main panel, `mainPan`.

Comment: @KingPopsicle , I see. Is there a way to get the `menuBarHeight`? I think it is 30 for me. But is there any method that returns the height?

Comment: @TNT , I don't know why I hadn't thought of that! It solved my first problem. But the second one and third one is still not solved. Any idea what's causing it? It seems that `(e.getY()+50 <= (getHeight() - colorPan.getHeight()))` in `mouseDragged` dosen't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `MouseListener`/`MouseMotionListener` to drawing panel instead of `GUI` like next :

```
  mainPan.addMouseListener(this);
  mainPan.addMouseMotionListener(this);
```

Or you can use [`SwingUtilities.convertPoint(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPoint(java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Component)) method to convert point from one component to another, like next:

```
Point convertPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(GUI.this, e.getPoint(), mainPan);
x=convertPoint.x;
y=convertPoint.y;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` in `mainPan`. This solved my first problem. Any idea about the second one and the third one?

Comment: Second one is solved! I subtracted the height of the title bar from `getHeight()` and it worked perfectly. The third problem isn't much problematic though!